# Javascript programming error

Tags: javascript

I want to print the following value in console,

```
root 1 = "The number to be printed" //
```

my code is

```
console.log("root 1 = " root1);
```

root1 variable contains the value of root 1, can't locate the error in my code, please help

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
console.log("root 1 = " + root1); //+ was missing here
```

You need to concatenate the variable value (`root1`) with the string literal `"root 1 = "`.

This is because as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression) when JS engine encountered the closing double quotes, it is either looking for a comma `,`, a closing brace `)` , operators like `+` `-` `*` `/`, or closing square bracket `]` if a property is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log("root 1 = " , root1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing the variable name deceleration you can't  define variable name with space like  "root 1" it should be like "root1", "root-1" .... 
 and second one is concat sign 
console.log("root1" + root1);

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the space between `root` and `1`

```
root1 = "The number to be printed"
```

And also use `+` sign for appending:

```
console.log("root 1 = " + root1);
```